# string alternates between vowel and consonent

Tags: javascript, string, if-statement, boolean

1. I am supposed to create a function that accepts a string as an argument and validates whether the vowels and consonants are in alternate order throughout. It should return true or false accordingly.
2. I tried this below, but it only comes out as true and does not check for the other possibilities of true and false. What am i missing/doing wrong? I dont want just the answer, I would also appreciate an explanation of what is going on in this function to set up how it should be properly.

```js
function isAlt(str) {
  let vowels = ["a", "e", "o", "i", "u"];
    
  for(i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if(vowels.indexOf(str[i]) >= 0) {
      if(vowels.indexOf(str[i+1]) === -1);
        return true;
    } else if(vowels.indexOf(str[i]) ===-1) {
      if(vowels.indexOf(str[i+1]) >= 0)
        return true; 
    } else if(vowels.indexOf(str[i]) >= 0) {
      if(vowels.indexOf(str[i+1]) >=0);
        return false;
    } else if(vowels.indexOf(str[i]) === -1) {
      if(vowels.indexOf(str[i+1]) === -1);
        return false; 
    }
  }
}

isAlt('apple'); // apple is false, amazon is true.
```

Comment: well you exit if it is true on first check.

Comment: Return false whenever the alternation condition fails. If you get to the end of the loop without returning, then return true.

Comment: The limit of your loop should be `str.length-1`. Otherwise, `str[i+1]` will access outside the string.

Answer (score 1):

You're returning `true` as soon as you find a pair that alternates, even though there could be non-alernating pairs later in the string. While you can return immediately when you find a non-alternating pair, you have to go through the entire string before you can return `true`.

You also should limit the `for` loop to `i < str.length - 1`, so that `str[i+1]` is within the string.

```js
function isAlt(str) {

  function isVowel(c) {
    let vowels = ["a", "e", "o", "i", "u"];
    return vowels.includes(c);
  }

  for (i = 0; i < str.length - 1; i++) {
    if (isVowel(str[i]) == isVowel(str[i + 1])) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

console.log(isAlt('apple'));
console.log(isAlt('amazon'));
```

The code is easier to read and less repetitive if you move the code that checks whether a letter is a vowel to a separate function. And then you don't need two cases for `str[i]` is a vowel and `str[i]` is not a vowel -- just test that the result of the adjacent characters is the same.

Comment: can you explain a little more of where the 'c' value comes from inside isvowel()?

Comment: It's the function parameter, it comes from the argument to the call. Functions and arguments are basic to programming.

Answer (score 1):

Your first inside `if` statement is not formatted properly.
`if(vowels.indexOf(str[i+1]) === -1);`

Here you are ending the `if` statement after the condition.
This means that if the outer `if` statement is satisfied, the program will return 'true' and end.

use proper syntax for inner `if` statements as well.

```
if (condition){
  // do something
}
```

I am guessing you meant:

```
if(vowels.indexOf(str[i]) >= 0) {
  if(vowels.indexOf(str[i+1]) === -1){
    return true;
  }
} else if...
```

If that is what you meant, the function is not getting past the first if and else statements. And when it does satisfy, it either returns true or the for loop continues. When it does continue, it encounters a situation where the true condition matches and it returns 'true'.

First, lets take your example of 'apple':

- 'a' satisfies the first if condition:`if(vowels.indexOf(str[i]) >= 0) {`
- `str[i+1]` satisfies the inside if condition which is looking for a consonant as 'p' is a consonant.
- The function returns `true` and the program ends.
- We don't even run the other `else if` statements.

Lets take another example 'tomato':

- 't' does not satisfy the first `if` statement and moves on to the first `else`
- 't' satisfies the first `else` statement which is looking for a consonant:  `else if(vowels.indexOf(str[i]) ===-1) {`
- and `str[i+1]` -'o' satisfies the inside `if` loop looking for a vowel: `if(vowels.indexOf(str[i+1]) >= 0){`
- Function returns `true` and program ends.

Now, lets take an example with no vowels in the beginning 'school':

- 's' does not satisfy the first `if` statement looking for a vowel and moves on to the first `else`
- 's' satisfies the first `else statement looking for a consonant:` else if(vowels.indexOf(str[i]) ===-1) {`and moves on to the inside`if` statement looking for a vowel.
- but the next letter 'c' does not satisfy that inside `if` loop that is looking for a vowel: `if(vowels.indexOf(str[i+1]) >= 0){`
- The next `else` statements are not read because you satisfied the first `else` statement.
- The `for` loop continues and i is incremented by 1.
- `str[i]` is now 'c' and does not satisfy the first `if` that is looking for a vowel.
- But it does again satisfy the following `else` statement looking for a consonant and program moves on to the inside `if statement` which is looking for the next letter to be a vowel.
- The next letter is 'h' and does not satisfy the inside loop so nothing happens and the 'for loop continues. `i` is again incremented by 1.
- `str[i]` is now 'h' and as before it will pass the first `if` statement and match the first `else` statement that is looking for a consonant.
- But here, it will pass the inside loop that is looking for a vowel as the next letter is 'o'.
- Function will return true as stated and the program will end.

So you see, no matter what word you put in the function will always return 'true'

To fix this: I recommend that you rethink the logic of your program.

Answer (score 1):

Using regex it's very simple:

```js
function isAlt(word) {
  return !/[aeiou]{2}|[^aeiou]{2}/.test(word);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function isAlt(str) {

let vowels = ["a", "e", "o", "i", "u"];
for(i = 0; i < str.length-1; i++) {
    if(vowels.indexOf(str[i]) >= 0 && vowels.indexOf(str[i+1])>=0)
                return false;
    else if(vowels.indexOf(str[i]) === -1 && vowels.indexOf(str[i+1])===-1)
            return false;
   }
   return true;
}
```

You can check the conditions where we have to return false such as two consecutive vowels or two consecutive consonants. You can also add capital vowels in the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
function isAlt(str){

    const vowels = "aeiouAEIOU"
    
    for (let i = 0; i < str.length-1; i++) {
        //Is the current character included in vowels? yes, ok then is the next character included in vowels? if yes then return false 
        if (vowels.includes(str[i])){
            if (vowels.includes(str[i+1])) {
                return false
            }
            //otherwise, is the current character not included in vowels? no? ok then is the next one not included in vowels? no? Then return false
        } else {
            if (!vowels.includes(str[i+1])) {
                return false
            }
        }
        
    }
        
     //otherwise continue the loop then return true
    return true;
}

isAlt("cacecicocu") // true
```